# Uncountability of “watermelon” and “pineapple”

Tags: uncountable-nouns

I noticed that “watermelon” and “pineapple” are used as uncountable when the flesh of them is focused. Likewise, “strawberry” can be used as uncountable when strawberries are chopped or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diced or puréed flesh of a fruit can be treated as uncountable (e.g. 'a bowl of stewed apple'), but this is less likely with small fruits that we normally eat as a quantity of whole ones. I think 'chopped strawberries' is more idiomatic than 'chopped strawberry'.